# Replacement for juliamap.googlelabs.com?

Tags: fractals

The site http://juliamap.googlelabs.com previously displayed the Julia set, letting you 
zoom into various portions to see its fractal nature.

However, this site no longer appears to work.

Is there another site that does the same thing?

I've tried several searches but all of them lead back to the Google Labs site.

I was thinking about programming something like this myself (it seems 
easy, emphasis on seems), but didn't want to duplicate work.

EDIT: Is anyone else seeing this site working? I can see lots of sites with Google Maps, so I don't think that's it, but not this one.

The Firefox "error console" shows the following for this site:

```
Timestamp: 09/24/2013 12:52:24 PM
Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
Source File: http://juliamap.googlelabs.com/
Line: 0

Timestamp: 09/24/2013 12:52:25 PM
Warning: Error: WebGL: OSMesa forced, but creating context failed -- aborting!
Source File: http://juliamap.googlelabs.com/juliamap_js.js
Line: 58

Timestamp: 09/24/2013 12:52:25 PM
Warning: Error: WebGL: OSMesa forced, but creating context failed -- aborting!
Source File: http://juliamap.googlelabs.com/juliamap_js.js
Line: 58

Timestamp: 09/24/2013 12:52:25 PM
Error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLCanvasElement.getContext]
Source File: http://juliamap.googlelabs.com/juliamap_js.js
Line: 58

Timestamp: 09/24/2013 12:52:29 PM
Warning: Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: http://juliamap.googlelabs.com/
Line: 0
```

(although I can often see sites even when Error Console claims there are fatal errors)

Answer (score 0):

The site seems to be working at the moment.